# SwiftUI TextField force lowercase

Tags: swiftui

I would like to use a specific TextField for url entries where the user could only enter lowercase characters, but I can't find any TextField modifier for this purpose. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a custom binding and set your state URL variable to the lowercased version of the input through it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var url: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        let binding = Binding<String>(get: {
            self.url
        }, set: {
            self.url = $0.lowercased()
        })

        return VStack {
            TextField("Enter URL", text: binding)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This works well. It can also be written as:

            TextField("Enter URL", text: Binding(get: {
                self.url
            }, set: { string in
                self.url = string.lowercased()
            }))

Answer (score 95):

TextField has a `.autocapitalization()` method.

You can use like this without custom binding:

```swift
TextField("URL", text: $url)
                    .keyboardType(.URL)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
```

For iOS 15 SwiftUI have a new `.textInputAutocapitalization()` method:

```swift
.textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
```

This means that any text input by the user will be `.lowercased()`

Comment: Note: This only works if you have them in this order for some reason. I had a `.foregroundColor()` in between `.keyboardType` and `.autocapitalization` and it didn't work for some reason. Also, this doesn't work if you copy and paste unfortunately.

Answer (score 17):

**XCODE 13 and 14**

**SwiftUI - IOS 15.0 and 16.0**

> *FROM:*
> `.autocapitalization(.none)`

> *TO:*
> `.textInputAutocapitalization(.never)`

Example:

```
TextField("Enter URL", text: $url)
    .keyboardType(.URL)
    .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
```

Comment: Be aware it's a keyboard modifier and that ".never" does not mean never. You can paste any mixed letter string into the text field, meaning the modifier will not lower case the string for you.

Answer (score 6):

if all you want is to "end up" with a lowercase string after the user press return, you could do this:

```
@State var txt: String = ""

var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $txt, onEditingChanged: { _ in
            self.txt = self.txt.lowercased()
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a more complicated but more flexible way, is something like this:

```
class LowerCaseStringFormatter: Formatter {

override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
    guard let str = obj as? NSString else { return nil }
    return str.lowercased as String
}

override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
    obj?.pointee = string.lowercased() as NSString
    return true
}

override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

and call it like this:

```
 TextField("type something...", value: $txt, formatter: LowerCaseStringFormatter())
```

Comment: Nice solution, but it seems formatter is deprecated on XCode 11.4 TextField, it throws exception "Extra argument 'formatter' in call"

Comment: not sure why you get that error. It works for me on, Xcode 11.4, on iPhone and iPad ios 13.4 and on macos catalina 10.15.4